# Access newly created column in withinColumn

Tags: apache-spark, scala-spark

I have the following dataset:

```
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
```

I want to create a new column *newValue* that takes the value of *newValue* from the previous row  and does something with it. For simplicity just increment by 3. If there is no previous column, in case of the first row, *value* should be taken. The result will look like this:

```
|value|newValue|
+-----+--------+
|    1|       1|
|    2|       4| # newValue previous row (1) + 3
|    3|       7| # newValue previous row (4) + 3
```

I tried it with the following code, but it seems that the new column *newValue* does not exist yet when trying to access the previous row. How can I access the newly created column within withColumn?

```
val data = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val dataset: Dataset[Int] = data.toDS()
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("value")

val result = dataset.withColumn("newValue", coalesce(lag("newValue", 1).over(windowSpec) + 3, $"value"))
```

This leads to the following error message:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter
> with name `newValue` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the
> following? [`value`]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if window function can be used to achieve this. You can do the calculation by converting DataFrame to RDD or List as a workaround. I tested it on an example, it seems to be working but not sure if this is an optimized approach.

```
df = spark.sql("select id as value, row_number() over(order by id) as rn from range(1, 4)")

firstVal = df.select("value").first()[0]
dfCount = df.count()
dataList = [[firsrtVal, 1]]

for i in range(2, dfCount + 1):
    dataList.append(list([dataList[-1][0] + 3, i]))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(dataList, ["newValue", "rn"])

finalDF = df.join(df2, 'rn', 'inner').select("value", "newValue")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Access to previous aggregated value is not possible.
For this particular case, `newValue` can be calculated as - sum of all previous values, plus current position multiplied on three:

```
val dataset: Dataset[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3, 12, 43).toDS()
val rangeWindow = Window.orderBy("value").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)
val formula = sum("value").over(rangeWindow) + count("*").over(rangeWindow) * 3

val result = dataset
  .withColumn("newValue", coalesce(formula, lit(1)))
```

Output:

```
+-----+--------+
|value|newValue|
+-----+--------+
|1    |1       |
|2    |4       |
|3    |9       |
|12   |15      |
|43   |30      |
+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is `running sum` with some constant value `3`

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|1    |
|2    |
|3    |
|4    |
|5    |
+-----+
```

```
df
.withColumn(
    "newValue", 
    sum(
        when(
            lag($"value", 1).over(Window.orderBy($"value")).isNotNull, 
            lit(3)
        ).otherwise($"value")
    )
    .over(Window.orderBy($"value"))
)
.show(false)
```

Output

```
+-----+--------+
|value|newValue|
+-----+--------+
|1    |1       |
|2    |4       | -- 1  + 3
|3    |7       | -- 4  + 3
|4    |10      | -- 7  + 3
|5    |13      | -- 10 + 3
+-----+--------+
```